# Is currentItem of AVPlayer key value observable?

Tags: ios, background, key-value-observing, avplayer, currentitem

I used a AvQueuePlayer for playing audio in background. And to keep the playlist of AvQueuePlayer not empty, I used key-value observing to keep an eye on the currentItem of AvQueuePlayer for getting ready to load a next play item. Sometimes it works well, but sometimes it failes.

Here is the crash report I received:

```
Date/Time:       2011-12-16 23:43:58.963 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4f2ecfe8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32f0aca4 objc_msgSend + 28
1   Foundation                      0x3165386c NSKVONotify + 24
2   Foundation                      0x31651bb0 -[NSKeyValueObservance observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 220
3   Foundation                      0x315fa7ea NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 210
4   Foundation                      0x315fa492 NSKeyValueDidChange + 230
5   Foundation                      0x315e666a - [NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 70
6   AVFoundation                    0x33f190f2 -[AVPlayerItem didChangeValueForKey:] +  26
7   AVFoundation                    0x33f1ceba __avplayeritem_fpItemNotificationCallback_block_invoke_1 + 2310
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x338da8e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 4
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x338d61ee    _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 306
10  CoreFoundation                  0x34c1d934 __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
11  CoreFoundation                  0x34badebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
12  CoreFoundation                  0x34baddc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
13  GraphicsServices                0x33e5e418 GSEventRunModal + 108
14  GraphicsServices                0x33e5e4c4 GSEventRun + 56
15  UIKit                           0x31272d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
16  UIKit                           0x31270800 UIApplicationMain + 664
17  WeatherTunes                    0x0004b31e main (main.m:17)
18  WeatherTunes                    0x0004b2ac start + 32
```

And here is how I use key-value observing:

```
[_queuePlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[_queuePlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And I looked up in the class reference of AvPlayer. Then I found that it was said the property "status" could be observable while it did not mention the currentItem. But I found some people use the property currentItem as observable. I am totally confused now. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, wanted to know when a song in an AVQueuePlayer finished. I ended up doing this instead, seemed safer.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(songFinishedWithNotification:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```